# Do i need to install express-session every time I use passport nodejs?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, express-session, passport-google-oauth

##### Do i need to install express-session every time I use passport nodejs?

I was following a tutorial on using Oauth (Google) with `Passport.js` and `Nodejs`, *The Net Ninja one*

And He didn't mention express-session and it worked for him

When I tried it it gave me the Error:

```
Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middleware?
```

And When I installed `express-session`, and did something like [this](https://www.passportjs.org/howtos/session/#:%7E:text=var%20session%20%3D%20require(%27express%2Dsession%27)%3B%0A%0Aapp.use(session(%7B%0A%20%20secret%3A%20%27keyboard%20cat%27%2C%0A%20%20resave%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20saveUninitialized%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20cookie%3A%20%7B%20secure%3A%20true%20%7D%0A%7D))%3B)

```js
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

... It worked Fine!

So, did I have to use `express-session`, and should I do every time I use `passport` oauth?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passport js authentification without sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514029/passport-js-authentification-without-sessions)

Comment: @sha'an Actually, I still can't understand why does it use sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A web application needs the ability to identify users as they browse from page to page. This series of requests and responses, each associated with the same user, is known as a session.

https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/sessions/

Sessions allow you to keep the user authenticated across multiple requests. Without sessions, each request would be treated as a new request, and the user would have to authenticate themselves again and again.

When you use `express-session`, Passport stores the authenticated user's information in a session cookie. This allows you to keep the user authenticated across multiple requests.

But, you can disable session support in Passport: [Passport js authentification without sessions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514029/passport-js-authentification-without-sessions)

Once you have disabled session support, you will need to store the auth information in a different way. One way to do this is to use JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). JWTs are a way of storing user information in a token that can be passed between the client and the server. JWTs are stateless, so they don't require sessions.

Have a look: https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/