# node.JS Express passport routing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, swig-template

I've created a simple project, with 3 pages: Home, Contact and About.

Everything was working, then I wanted to add users registration with mongo.

So I followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619)

But, when I add somes new routes, I can't acces any more pages.

This was my `index.js` when I can acces my 3 pages

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});



/* GET contact page. */
router.get('/contact', function(req, res) {
    res.render('contact');
});

/* POST contact page (submit). */
router.post('/contact', function(req, res) {
    res.render('contact', { name: req.param('name') });
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

/* POST home page (submit). */
router.post('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', { comm: req.param('comm') });
});


/* GET about page. */
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('about');
});


module.exports = router;
```

all simple and working.
and now, it's like that :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});



/* GET contact page. */
router.get('/contact', function(req, res) {
    res.render('contact');
});

/* POST contact page (submit). */
router.post('/contact', function(req, res) {
    res.render('contact', { name: req.param('name') });
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

/* POST home page (submit). */
router.post('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', { comm: req.param('comm') });
});


/* GET about page. */
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('about');
});


module.exports = router;

module.exports = function(passport){

  // /* GET login page. */
  // router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //   // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
  //   res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
  // });

  /* Handle Login POST */
  router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash : true
  }));

  /* GET Registration Page */
  router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
  });

  /* Handle Registration POST */
  router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
  }));

  return router;
}
```

and now, no routes are showed.

Any ideas ?

thanks !

EDIT :  `app.js`

```
var express      = require('express');
var path         = require('path');
var favicon      = require('static-favicon');
var logger       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var swig         = require('swig');

var dbConfig = require('./db.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url);

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


// view engine setup
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// view cache
app.set('view cache', false);
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: show the code that calls this module (i.e, app.js)

Comment: I appreciate this is an old post, but if you're still about: Is there a reason you're assigning model.export twice? I'm new to node so perhaps it's legal, but from a js pov it seems like you're overwriting all the stuff from the initial model.export

Comment: I don't remember why, a simple beginner mistake I think, as you said it's an old post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your module expects a `passport` object

```
module.exports = function(passport){
```

but you're not calling it with a passport object in app.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

also, you'll need to defined passport before calling the routes module. So in the end you'll need to modify your app.js to look something like this:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

...
var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
...
app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: My problem was that passport wouldn't authenticate any route that was outside the main.js file. Adding the passport parameter to the export worked wonders. Thank you!