# Understanding passport serialize deserialize

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, serialization, passport.js

How would you explain the workflow of Passport's serialize and deserialize methods to a layman.

1. Where does `user.id` go after `passport.serializeUser` has been called?
2. We are calling `passport.deserializeUser` right after it where does it fit in the workflow?

   ```
   // used to serialize the user for the session
   passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
       done(null, user.id); 
      // where is this user.id going? Are we supposed to access this anywhere?
   });

   // used to deserialize the user
   passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
       User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
           done(err, user);
       });
   });
   ```

I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. I have a complete working app and am not running into errors of any kind.

I just wanted to understand what exactly is happening here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 645, accepted):

> 1. Where does `user.id` go after `passport.serializeUser` has been called?

The user id (you provide as the second argument of the `done` function) is saved in the session and is later used to retrieve the whole object via the `deserializeUser` function.

`serializeUser` determines which data of the user object should be stored in the session. The result of the serializeUser method is attached to the session as `req.session.passport.user = {}`. Here for instance, it would be (as we provide the user id as the key) `req.session.passport.user = {id: 'xyz'}`

> 2. We are calling `passport.deserializeUser` right after it where does it fit in the workflow?

The first argument of `deserializeUser` corresponds to the key of the user object that was given to the `done` function (see 1.). So your whole object is retrieved with help of that key. That key here is the user id (key can be any key of the user object i.e. name,email etc).
In `deserializeUser` that key is matched with the in memory array / database or any data resource.

The fetched object is attached to the request object as `req.user`

**Visual Flow**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});              │
                 │ 
                 │
                 └─────────────────┬──→ saved to session
                                   │    req.session.passport.user = {id: '..'}
                                   │
                                   ↓           
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
                   ┌───────────────┘
                   │
                   ↓ 
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });            └──────────────→ user object attaches to the request as req.user   
});
```

Comment: So is `user.id` saved as `req.session.passport.user` or is `user` itself stored as `req.session.passport.user`

Comment: @A.B I wrote code to find user from the id which has been passed to deserialize method as first parameter. But in every request it is retrieving user from db. This makes performance loss for db. What else should I write to deserialize function to check whether if it is exist on session or not?

Comment: object is retrieved from req.user afterwards :) @uzay95

Comment: So later on in my program, whenever I need information from the session, calling req.user.id should give me back the user in session and by consequence, call deserializeUser, correct?

Comment: @A.B I do not understand what you suggested to uzay95. So in my session I have only user._id. But on every request, I have to use that id to deserialized from database aka findUserByID and that will put it into req.user. How do I avoid making such call on every request?

Comment: @Zanko You could put the whole user object into the session data, but that is usually not a good idea because it can have other side effects. For example, when the user updates his/her username you have to update the session data too, otherwise you'll get tickets because of "the broken rename feature". That's a relatively harmless example. Same could happen with permission bits or equal sensitive data (Oops...). Essentially the same problems you always run into if you have duplicate data. TL;DR - Don't do it.

Comment: is passortjs a cookie-based Authentication OR  Token-based Authentication?

Comment: I still did not get what is the benefit of `deSerializeUser` method?

Comment: Sir, Can we talk I have few doubts, It would be a great help if I could talk to you

Comment: @A.B I know it's been quite some time since you answered this but could you clarify where the callback `done(err, user);` points to?

Comment: @Valamorde Done is a callback function managed internally by passport and it takes you to the next step , success/failure etc depending on the parameter. Consider it similar to calling next for ease of understanding

Comment: @A.B thanks but I already get that, I was looking for it's original callback meaning where the value is returned to!

Comment: Wonderful answer. Although I still wonder how and when does `req.user` come into the picture? 
`req.user` looks like `{ _id: 5ca6153dd508054604805e55,
  username: 'Rishav Rungta',
  googleId: '105955******623074113',
  avatar: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-gZZ***',
  __v: 0 }`

I have this data schema ofc but I really dont know when do I put this in as `req.user`. I havent ever used `req.session.passport.user` although my `done` methods are exactly the same. Whenever I want the user I just grab it from `req.user`

Comment: @Rishav it has been very long that i havent looked into it, but i think  as it mentioned in the answer (just at the bottom), user object attaches to the request as req.user in deserialize method (when done is called)

Comment: @A.B How did I miss that. Sorry. Also say I name it as `foo` instead `user` will it be attached as `req.foo`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `req.session.passport.user = {id: '..'}` part of the diagram is slightly off, and should be `req.session.passport.user = 785352` instead, where `785352` is `user.id`. I'm having trouble console logging to prove it, but it seems like it'd make sense. When you call `done(null, user.id);`, it'd make sense to take the second argument - `user.id` in this case - and assign it to `req.session.passport.user`, instead of assigning it to `req.session.passport.user.id`. Because what if you instead pass in `user`? `req.sesssion.passport.user.id = user` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Suppose that the ```user``` object passed to ```serializeUser()``` contains data on a brand new user who is not yet in the database. In that case, shouldn't we add the new user to the database within```serializeUser()```? Otherwise, how will we be able to add to our DB those fields of the user object obtained from the OAuth provider that we need to include in the user's database record (e.g., ```profileImageUrl```, ```provider```, etc.)?

Comment: I think I can answer my own question! The place where we add new users to the database is in the callback function defined when we instantiate a new strategy: ```function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)```. I believe the ```profile``` parameter contains the profile info obttained from the strategy (e.g., a third-party OAuth provider such as GitHub). In this callback, we can check whether the user with this profile exists in our database and, if not, we can add the user.

Comment: referencing a great blog post https://hackernoon.com/passportjs-the-confusing-parts-explained-edca874ebead for further overall clarity

Comment: could you inform us which tool you have used to make the flow diagram?

Comment: @A.B Do you know why `passport.deserializeUser` is called [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374696/why-is-passport-deserializeuser-called-after-req-user-has-been-restored) `req.user` has been restored?

Comment: @anakha I didnt use any tool and draw it manually, but there might be some tools now

Comment: `passport.initialize()` returns a middleware that among other things [configures the `session` strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/v0.4.1/lib/authenticator.js#L32). `passport.session()` returns a middleware that [wraps](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/v0.4.1/lib/authenticator.js#L233) the `session` strategy. The `session` strategy takes user id from the session, passes it to the deserialize callback, and puts the result into [`req.user`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/v0.4.1/lib/strategies/session.js#L67).

Comment: Well, actually the `session` strategy is configured when you [require `passport`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/v0.4.1/lib/index.js#L13). The `initialize` middleware does [something different](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/v0.4.1/lib/middleware/initialize.js#L45-L51).

Comment: What is the `User` object in the `User.findById(id, function(err, user) ` line?  Where does that come from?  Is it imported? If so, from where?

Comment: is it save to pass the whole user object (including password) to the done function as a second augument ?
like this: passport.deserializedUser((id,done)=>done(null, getUserById(id)))

Comment: is it safe for include password in user object at deserialize? Because i have middleware res.locals.user = req.user for access user from view and it have password. -- 

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
   done(err, user);
  })
 });

Answer (score 22):

For anyone using Koa and [koa-passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-passport):

Know that the key for the user set in the serializeUser method (often a unique id for that user) will be stored in:

`this.session.passport.user`

When you set in `done(null, user)` in deserializeUser where 'user' is some user object from your database:

`this.req.user`
OR
`this.passport.user`

for some reason `this.user` Koa context never gets set when you call done(null, user) in your deserializeUser method.

So you can write your own middleware after the call to app.use(passport.session()) to put it in this.user like so:

```
app.use(function * setUserInContext (next) {
  this.user = this.req.user
  yield next
})
```

If you're unclear on how serializeUser and deserializeUser work, just hit me up on twitter. [@yvanscher](https://twitter.com/yvanscher)

Comment: Sorry for necroposting here, but I do have a concern now after reading the deserialize explanation. I've posted a question about this here on SO:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154047/simple-auth-with-passport-local-and-deserializeuser-problem

Comment: Super helpful, but still having some issues reading the user from other routes. Can anyone help me out here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709882/koa-passport-oauth2-save-token-to-state

Answer (score 22):

Passport uses `serializeUser` function to persist user data (after successful authentication) into session. Function `deserializeUser` is used to retrieve user data from session.

Both `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions check first argument passed to them, and if it's of type function, `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` do nothing, but put those functions in a stack of functions, that will be called, afterwards (when passed first arguments are not of type function).
Passport needs the following setup to save user data after authentication in the session:

```
app.use(session({ secret: "cats" }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

The order of used middlewares matters. It's important to see, what happens, when a new request starts for authorization:

- session middleware creates session (using data from the `sessionStore`).
- `passport.initialize` assigns `_passport` object to request object, checks if there's a session object, and if it exists, and field `passport` exists in it (if not - creates one), assigns that object to `session` field in `_passport`. At the end, it looks, like this:

  ```
  req._passport.session = req.session['passport']
  ```

  So, `session` field **references** object, that assigned to `req.session.passport`.
- `passport.session` looks for `user` field in `req._passport.session`, and if finds one, passes it to `deserializeUser` function and calls it. `deserializeUser` function assigns `req._passport.session.user` to `user` field of request object (if find one in `req._passport.session.user`). This is why, if we set user object in `serializeUser` function like so:

  ```
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, JSON.stringify(user)); 
  });
  ```

  We then need to parse it, because it was saved as `JSON` in `user` field:

  ```
   passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
     // parsed user object will be set to request object field `user`
     done(err, JSON.parse(user));
   });
  ```

So, `deserializeUser` function firstly called, when you setup Passport, to put your callback in `_deserializers` function stack. Second time, it'll be called in `passport.session` middleware to assign `user` field to request object. That also triggers our callback (that we put in `passport.deserializeUser()`) before assigning `user` field.

`serializeUser` function called first, when you setup Passport (similarly to `deserializeUser` function), but it'll be used to serialize user object for saving in session. Second time, it'll be called, in `login/logIn (alias)` method, that attached by Passport, and used to save user object in session. `serializeUser` function also checks `_serializers` stack with already pushed to it functions (one of which added, when we set up Passport):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) ...
```

and calls them, then assigns user object (strignified) or user id to `req._passport.session.user`. It is important to remember that `session` field directly references `passport` field in `req.session` object. In that way user **saved** in session (because `req._passport.session`  references object `req.session.passport`, and `req._passport.session` is modified in each incoming request by `passport.initialize` middleware).
When request ends, `req.session` data will be stored in `sessionStore`.

What happens after successful authorization, when the second request starts:

- `session` middleware gets session from `sessionStore`, in which our user data already saved
- `passport.initialize` checks if there's session and assigns `req.session.passport` to `req._passport.session`
- `passport.session` checks `req._passport.session.user` and deserializes it. At this stage (if `req._passport.session.user` is truthy), we'll have `req.user` and `req.isAuthenticated()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, we are just storing the user-id in the session using **serializer** and when we need the user model instance, we use that user-id to search in the database which is done using **deserializer**.

As long as the session is active and the user is authenticated,

```
req.session.passport.user
```

will always correspond to user model instance.

If we don't save user-id into the session and if there is any redirect, we will have no way to know if the user is authenticated.

once the user is authenticated `req.session.passport.user` will be set.
and hence all future requests will know that the user has been authenticated.

hope this simplifies.

Answer (score 2):

## So I got stuck on this for quite awhile so I made a quick setup file so no one ever gets stuck on this garbage ever again

passportmgmt.js

```
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('./db-schemas/models').UserModel;
/*^^^^^^^^^^^ delete above import and modify below definition as needed 
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
const UserModel = mongoose.model('collection_name', UserSchema);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Change UserModel to User */
const passport = require('passport');

function passportSetupUwU(app) {
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const session = require('express-session');
    const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.set('trust proxy', 1);
    app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoDBStore({
        uri: "mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name",
        collection: "collection_name"
    })
    }));

    // Passport.js
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
}

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    console.log("serializing user uwu:" + JSON.stringify(user))
    process.nextTick(function() {
        return cb(null, user.id)
    })
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, cb) {
    console.log("deserializing user owo:" + JSON.stringify(id))
    User.findOne({id:id}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return cb(err)}
        return cb(null, user);
    })
});

passport.use(new localStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    console.log("attempted login with %s:%s", username, password);
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'No such user exists.' });

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (res === false) return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            
            return done(null, user);
        });
    });
}));

module.exports = {setup: passportSetupUwU}
```

## now just import and run the passportSetupUwU function in app.js and you're good to go:

app.js exerpt

```
// some example middleware and stuff i happened to have
const PPSetup = require('./passportmgmt').setup
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//
// <- PUT IT LIKE HERE OR SOMETHING
//
PPSetup(app);

// some example routes and api endpoints i happened to have
app.use('/api/', apiRouter);
apiRouter.use('/', indexRouter);
apiRouter.use('/users', usersRouter);

apiRouter.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can upgrade the old serialize and deserialize with this code, please up this post for new solution.**

```js
        passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
          process.nextTick(function() {
            cb(null, { id: user.id, username: user.username });
          });
        });
        
        passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) {
          process.nextTick(function() {
            return cb(null, user);
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**A visual workflow for Passport's serialize and deserialize methods:**

1. User logs in to your application and provides their credentials.
2. Passport uses the serializeUser function to take the user object and convert it into a session object.
3. Passport stores the session object on the server and sends a session cookie to the user's browser.
   4.User makes a request to your application.
   5.Passport uses the deserializeUser function to take the session object and convert it back into a user object.
4. Passport passes the user object to your application, which can then use it to determine if the user is authenticated or not.
5. If the user is authenticated, your application will allow them to access the requested resource.
6. If the user is not authenticated, your application will deny access and redirect them to the login page.

**Here's a visual representation of the workflow:**

```
    +------------+             +---------------+
|            |             |               |
| User Login |             | Session Object |
|            |    serializeUser    |               |
+-----+------+   ------------------>   +---------+
      |                                 |           |
      |                                 | Store on  |
      |                                 | Server    |
      |                                 |           |
+-----+------+   <------------------   +---------+
|            |             |               |
| User Request |    deserializeUser    |               |
|            |   ------------------>   |             |
+------------+             |               +-----------+
      |                   |
      |                   |
      |                   |
+-----+------+   <------------------   +---------+
|            |             |               |
| Authenticated |             |     User     |
|  or not       |             |             |
|            |             |               |
+------------+             +---------------+
```

I hope this helps clarify the workflow of Passport's serialize and deserialize methods!