# How to set firebase rules based on database user id (not uid)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Hi I have a list of users in my fb database. The user id is auto-generated after successful registration and each user entry has the name, email, and uid. Also, each of these properties is being indexed in /index so that I can easily look up a user's id given their uid.

According to the docs, firebase says to use write: $user_id === auth.uid

How can I accomplish this using the generated ID instead of the uid?

here's the fb db: https://medviz.firebaseio.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Your users object there will be users like this

```
users : {
 user1234abc:{         
       name: "abc"         
    },                    
    user2434dbcc:{         
       name: "abc"         
    } 
}
```

you will have many `unique key/user nodes` in users object, eg `user1234abc`, `user2434dbcc`

That unique key can be named any `variable` in rules it not necessary to call it `$user_id`, you can call it anything you want for example you can name the variable as `$any_variable` for unique user keys

and in auth.id whenever user successfully authenticate that same unique id is in `auth.uid` so you can any where math that `auth.uid` when you are editing the info related to that user

For example if `auth.uid` contains `user1234abc` and if `user1234abc` is editing this object `user1234abc:{name: "abc"  }` thn accordind to .write rule he will be able to

See the updated view below

**Updated Visual Hierarchy:**

```
--schema--
users : {
           ________________
          |
    user1234abc:{          |
       name: "abc"         |  
    },                     |
    user2434dbcc:{         |
       name: "abc"         |
    }                      |
}                  key can be name as any variable  in rules
                           |
-- rules--
                           | 
{                          | 
  "rules": {               |
    "users": {             |
      ".read": true,       |
           ________________|___________  
          |                            |
         \|/                           | 
      "$any_variable": {              \|/     
        ".write": "$any_variable === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it was just for an example i know there is something fishy about it ;)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if about arrows thn here you go :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637609/understanding-passport-serialize-deserialize/27637668#27637668

Comment: I was trying to compliment you on the use of a diagram in explaining a technical concept. Sorry if I came across as snarky.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes i got it, bit late though ;) thankyou :)

Comment: Thanks, @A.B Please correct me but auth.uid would be what Firebase generates for a new user? If so, how would I get my unique user's table id (ala, -Jdfsdj34h3kjasfh ) to be what is allowed permissions?

Comment: also appreciate the acsii ;)

Comment: @irth thanks, i have updated the Answer plus ascii ;)

Comment: Cheers, please let me ellab.. my users are posted in the database like any normal property and get assigned a firebase random string. In a separate index table, users are listed by their uid (amongst other properties) which references the proper user id generated string. Is it true that as long as the uid is a property anywhere down the chain, a user could have permissions?

Comment: sorry i was ill and couldnt type, the node in users has a key that is a user's unique id , that is to be the node key to be called a user's id--- and in auth.id the id generated with respective provider will be stored