# Get current login user sails.js + passport.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I am new to **passport** and **sails.js**. I created an user login follow by this [article](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/). It's work fine and I can do both login and logout.

However, I try to access current login user in some `Controller` but I cannot get the user data.

I have reading some topic here and it said something likes this

```
test : function(req,res){
    console.log(req.user);
}
```

I try this with my **TestController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    test : function(req,res){
        console.log(req.user);
        res.send("test");
        res.status(200).end();
    }
};
```

I got `undefined`.

Comment: Can u post Your current Controller Codes?

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Sure wait a second please.

Comment: its get `undefined` because you not passing the session of user in your test Controller

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Could you show me an example please ?

Comment: `test : function(req,res){
    console.log(req.session.user);
}` check this

Comment: @AkhileshSingh I still got undefined with `req.session.user`

Comment: You need to deserialize first before accessing req.user

Comment: Ok it's work now with your comment I realize to check something in deserialize function. and I see that something wrong with field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixing this problem Thanks to @godfather

Before you can access to user object from request you have to `deserialize` it first.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findOne({
        id: id 
    }, function (err, user) {
        delete user.password
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

This `deserializeUser` function will attach your user object to request object. So, this will make you can access to current login user from other `Controller`.

More information here : [Understanding passport serialize deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637609/understanding-passport-serialize-deserialize/27637809#27637809)