# Koa v2, getting user object after passport-loca login

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, koa, passport-local

I'm failing to get user object to the next middleware after `passport.authenticate('local', {session: false})` middleware passes successfully.

Here is how my code looks like.

**In passport Local Strategy**

```js
passport.use(new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {

    User.findOne({username}, (err, user) => {
        
        if(err) { return done(err) }

        if(!user) { return done(err) }

        user.comparePasswords(password, async(err, isMatch) => {

            if(!isMatch) { return done(null, false) }

            done(null, user);
        });
    });
}));
```

which *I think* is suppose to return the user object if login is successfully made.

Then in my **routes** I have

```js
const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});

router.post('/login', requireAuth, signIn);
```

As when I hit `/signin` the passport middleware is called and then when it's done `signIn` middleware is called *Something i'm  expecting,* **with my logged in user object**.

But when I check in my **signIn** middleware nothing is passed (*In the request or response*) object.

Here is my **signIn** middleware

```js
const signIn = async (ctx, next) => {
    const res = ctx.response;
    const req = ctx.request;

    console.log('response', res); //- Nothing from passport
    console.log('request', req); //- Nothing from passport
    await next();
};
```

I need to pass the logged in user from passport to the next middleware so I can use the user Id to make a jwt.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think `const res = await ctx.response;` & `const req = await ctx.request;` is right because this expects the request and response objects in context to be promises yet to be executed, but I don't think that's the case, is it?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha no it's not, i tried in the normal way (without `awaits`) around but that didn't work either.

Lemme fix the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've got it to work with `passReqToCallback` i'm not sure if this is the proper way though, *To override the request body* but that's what got this app to work for now.

**Here is my passport.js** file *The only file that changned*.

```js
passport.use(new localStrategy(
  {passReqToCallback: true},
  async(req, username, password, done) => {

    User.findOne({username}, (err, user) => {
        
        if(err) { return done(err) }

        if(!user) { return done(err) }

        user.comparePasswords(password, async(err, isMatch) => {

            if(!isMatch) { return done(null, false) }

            req.body = user;
            await done(null, user);
        });
    });
}));
```

Yeah i'm overriding my `req.body` with the user obtained from db.

I honestly don't know why i still keep the `done(null, user)` i could as well just said `done(null, true)` but that's just me.

If anyone has a better solution please post cause i'm not really *feeling* this code.

Thanks.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to searialize and deserialize the user to the request, looks at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637609/understanding-passport-serialize-deserialize..

Comment: @A__ Hello, I think I didn't use serializing/deserializing because I was using JWTs and not sessions. But that definitely looks like the correct way to do it. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

With koa passport, to access the authenticated user in other routes/middleware use `ctx.state.user`:

```
app.use(async ctx => { 
  ctx.state.user;
})
```

From koa passport [readme](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport)
and search for [`state.user`](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport/search?q=state.user)