# req.user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, restify

I want to write a REST-API with NodeJS+Restify and PassportJS for the authentication. 
When the user logs in, I generate a sessionId and store it in a session, which I create myself.

```
var Passport                = require( 'passport' );
var PassportBearerStrategy  = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy;
// Authentication
Passport.use( new PassportBearerStrategy( function( sessionId, cb ) {
    Auth.getSession( sessionId, function( userId ){
        cb( ( !!userId ), { userId: userId }, userId );
    });
}));

server.get(
    '/user',
    Passport.authenticate( 'bearer' ),
    function( req, res, next ){
        console.info( req.user  ); // undefined
        respond( res, {} );
        return next();
    }
);
```

Everything works except, that in the function bellow, `req.user` is `undefined`. I read, that you have to enable session. But I already implemented my own session, I do not need another one.
All I need is that, if I say `cb( true, user )` it arrives in the function below.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I have never used that strategy, only local-strategy. On local, you need to have a function to serialize and to deserialize the user. It's the desarialize function which gives you the user that will later be accesible through req.user. Aren't you missing this function?

Comment: @yBrodsky, You are right, these functions are missing. I added them exactly like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637609/understanding-passport-serialize-deserialize

But req.user is still undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I get from the code in [this example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-http-bearer-example/blob/master/server.js) the callback `cb` follows the standard node format, so gets an error as first argument and the user as second. I think that callback is what set req.user and manage all post-auth boilerplate. You should try to call it as `cb(null, user)