# koa passport oauth2 save token to state

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, koa

So I'm trying to save an access token to the state within Koa, just for use later and saving having to pass it around the client.

Following the [passport oauth2 documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) for Koa, I'm struggling to persist anything to `ctx.state`...

**Koa / passport oauth2 setup:**

```
server.koaApp.use(koaSession(
  {
    key: sessionKey,
    rolling: true,
    maxAge: sessionMaxAge,
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true,
    // @ts-ignore
    domain: undefined
  },
  server.koaApp,
));

// set up passport sessions here
function createPassport() {
  const passport = new KoaPassport();

  passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: oauthClientAuthUrl,
    tokenURL: oauthClientTokenUrl,
    clientID: oauthClientId,
    clientSecret: oauthClientSecret,
    callbackURL: oauthClientRedirectUrl,
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cb) {
    cb(null, {id: 'somedudesID', accessToken});
  }));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });

  return passport;
};
```

**Route declarations that should set and read accesstoken:**

```
router.get('/authorize', passport.authenticate('oauth2'), (ctx: any) => {
        const { accessToken } = ctx.session.passport.user;
        ctx.state.accessToken = accessToken;
        ctx.status = 200;
      });

    router.get('/get-token-from-state', (ctx: any) => {
      console.log(ctx.state.accessToken); // undefined
    });
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is `ctx.state.accessToken` undefined when doing a get to `/get-token-from-state`?
2. Should I even be trying to persist the access token like this? Is there another way to obtain the accessToke in other routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answering my own question here, it was a number of things:

1. "sameSite: 'lax'" was needed
2. Cookies of the session were not being saved in browser because the domains were slightly off (port numbers were different.

I was able to proxy this locally and all good!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same annoying experience.
What helped was removing `koa-session` and replace it with `koa-generic-session`. Then I setup a memory store -> now it works :)

Iam not sure if storing the token inside a memory session is the best idea - but right now its my first draft.
Its only a little code block to get in touch with keycloak.

**server.js**

```js
    var app = new Koa();
    app.keys = ['keys', 'keykeys'];
    var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

    // Session
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'some secret',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        store: memoryStore
      }));

    // Passport
    const passport = require('./oauth2')
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
```

**oauth2.js**

```js
const request = require('request');
const passport = require('koa-passport');
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;


const clientId = "b2m";
const clientSecrect = "57ce5bba-f336-417f-b9c2-06157face88f";

OAuth2Strategy.prototype.userProfile = function (accessToken, done) {
  var options = {
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
      headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'request',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
      }
  };

  request(options, callback);

  function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
          return done(error);
      }
      var info = JSON.parse(body);
      return done(null, info);
  }
};

passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
    tokenURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    clientID: clientId,
    clientSecret: clientSecrect,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log('#########################################################');
    console.log('Authenticated with OAuth2');
    console.log('accessToken', accessToken);
    console.log('refreshToken', refreshToken);
    
    var user = {
      accessToken: accessToken,
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
      profile: profile
    };
    console.log('user', user);

    return cb(null, user);
  }
));

/* Example: storing user data received from the strategy callback in the session, i.e. in `req.session.passport.user` */
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });
  
/* Example: getting the user data back from session and attaching it to the request object, i.e. to `req.user` */
passport.deserializeUser(function (user, next) {
    /*
      Example: if only a user identifier is stored in the session, this is where
      the full set could be retrieved, e.g. from a database, and passed to the next step
    */
    next(null, user);
});

module.exports = passport;
```

Comment: Thanks @Axel! I'm a little further along with your approach but still unable to pull the user from `ctx.state` or `ctx.session`. Logs:

ctx.state = {
  _passport: {
    instance: KoaPassport {
      _key: 'passport',
      _strategies: [Object],
      _serializers: [Array],
      _deserializers: [Array],
      _infoTransformers: [],
      _framework: [Object],
      _userProperty: 'user',
      _sm: [SessionManager]
    }
  }
}

ctx.session = {
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: '/',
    overwrite: true,
    signed: true,
    maxAge: 86400000
  }
}