# Why is passport.deserializeUser called after req.user has been restored?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

According to the [Passport Documentation on Sessions](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/)

> ...only the user ID is serialized to the session, keeping the amount
> of data stored within the session small. When subsequent requests are
> received, this ID is used to find the user, which will be restored to
> req.user.

However my [test SPA](https://github.com/shanemcandrewai/agenda-spa/blob/stov/app.js) which is based on [Passport form-based authentication sample](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js) with debug messages added indicates `req.user` has already been restored before the `app.get` route handler is triggered.

Here is the output from an HTTP POST where the username and passport fields are empty -

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
agenda-spa app listening at http://localhost:3000
handling request for:  / POST
handling request for:  / GET
xxx get root
xxx req.user  undefined
handling request for:  /style.css GET
```

`req.user` is undefined as expected

Here is the output from an HTTP POST with an authenticated username and password

```
handling request for:  / POST
xxx passport.use  sss
xxx findByUsername sss
xxx password match
xxx serializeUser { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
xxx auth success
xxx deserializeUser 1
xxx findById 1
handling request for:  / GET
xxx get root
xxx req.user  { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
xxx deserializeUser 1
xxx findById 1
handling request for:  /style.css GET
```

I would expect it to be -

```
...
xxx deserializeUser 1
xxx findById 1
xxx req.user  { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
...
```

Why is `passport.deserializeUser` called after `req.user` has been restored?

Answer (score 1):

First, in my case I get:

```
xxx passport.use  sss
xxx findByUsername sss
xxx password match
xxx serializeUser { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
xxx auth success
xxx deserializeUser 1
xxx findById 1
handling request for:  / GET
xxx get root
xxx req.user  { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
```

To reproduce the issue I run the following script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
rm cookies.txt || true
args=(
-sSv -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt
)
curl "${args[@]}" -d 'username=sss&password=sss' localhost:3000
curl "${args[@]}" localhost:3000
```

Let's add some debugging information to understand where requests start:

```
$ DEBUG=* node app.js
...
  express:router dispatching POST / +10s
  express:router session  : / +1ms
  express-session no SID sent, generating session +1ms
  express:router initialize  : / +3ms
  express:router authenticate  : / +1ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : / +0ms
handling request for:  / POST
xxx passport.use  sss
xxx findByUsername sss
xxx password match
xxx serializeUser { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
xxx auth success
  express-session saving y4TUFn7tzccSARC7kHiDbuKY8qXj1sCU +13ms
  express-session split response +1ms
  express-session set-cookie connect.sid=s%3Ay4TUFn7tzccSARC7kHiDbuKY8qXj1sCU.yxt3TbHx4HSzm03JMrtPcTPrm3K40FbHiuS6NGT%2Fd7E; Path=/; HttpOnly +3ms
...
  express:router dispatching GET / +14ms
  body-parser:urlencoded skip empty body +0ms
  express:router session  : / +0ms
  express-session fetching y4TUFn7tzccSARC7kHiDbuKY8qXj1sCU +1ms
  express-session session found +1ms
  express:router initialize  : / +1ms
  express:router authenticate  : / +0ms
xxx deserializeUser 1
xxx findById 1
  express:router <anonymous>  : / +1ms
handling request for:  / GET
xxx get root
xxx req.user  { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
...
```

As such what is output for the second request in your case is:

```
xxx deserializeUser 1
xxx findById 1
handling request for:  / GET
xxx get root
xxx req.user  { id: 1, username: 'sss', password: 'sss' }
xxx deserializeUser 1
xxx findById 1
```

So it's as you expected, but for some reason the session strategy is triggered twice. That I can't reproduce.