# user is not defined: Nodejs/Express + Passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

My problem is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434893/node-express-passport-req-user-undefined) however the answers seems to not work for me (I see that user never picked an answer also).

I have a fresh install of Nodejs and Express.

My setup:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser('hithere'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'hithere',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('Serialize user called.');
  return done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log('Deserialize user called.');
  return done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    console.log('local strategy called with: %s', username);
    return done(null, {username:username, password:password});
  }));


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.get('/success', function(req, res) {
  req.send('sucess!');
});
app.get('/failure', function(req, res) {
  req.send('failure!');
})
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/success', failureRedirect: '/failure' }));
```

I'm using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

My LocalStrategy, serialize and deserialize user are all getting called, but frankly I'm not really sure what to put on the deserialize function on this test app.

Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: This will only occur if there are some issues with your deserializeUser() code. try to figure out any typos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get `user is not defined` because `user` in fact is not defined in your `deserializeUser()` callback. If you look at the example in the Sessions section on [this page](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/), you will see that you are supposed to look up the `id` in your database and pass a user object (generated from the result of the database query) to the `done` callback.

For simple testing purposes, you could easily just use a fake user object until you have a database set up:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log('Deserialize user called.');
  return done(null, { firstName: 'Foo', lastName: 'Bar' });
});
```