# Node Http Module & IIS - Setting Secure Cookie

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js, iisnode

I aim using secure flagged cookies in a node app in IIS.

I'm working on a Next.js app and also trying to deploy on IIS to meet some corporate requirements. I've already configured IIS by installing iisnode, URL rewrite module, nodejs to server and mostly followed the footsteps in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLsx0iraA-Y) video.

SSR and static structures are just working fine. IIS already has its own SSL certificate. According to my researchs;

> iisnode requests from IIS to your node app running express. The ssl
> connection is terminated at IIS and your node app receives an http
> request. When the app requires cookies over a secure connection it
> fails.

So when it comes to cookies with secure options, this creates issues. As I understand I need to tell node server to trust the proxy. I found a way in express but I'd like to continue using node http module and there have to be a way in my opinion since Express is just made on top of the http module. Unfortunately I wasn't be able to find any resource about it unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871133/secure-cookiesession-when-using-iisnode) Express example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution by creating another custom server file which is built with express. Actually, as I mentioned, from the beginning I kind of knew that there is a way to achieve trust proxy setting with express server. But since I'm already using node http module, I did not wanted to change this structure and wanted to learn how this proxy setting could be done in this module. I was not able to find the way to do it but since I know the express.js is built upon node http module; there have to be a way.

Unfortunately either I couldn't find it or it was harder to implement then express js. I have already a development server with http module and it also reads ssl certificate etc. Instead of completely removing it, I added another file that has expressjs and proxy setting.

The following codes are not much a big deal but it might be helpful to someone because these provide custom Next.js servers that have SSL environment for development and proxy server production.

**server with express & proxy**

```
// This server file intended to use behind IIS.
const next = require("next");
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev: false, dir: ".", quiet: false });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.set('trust proxy', 1)

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log(`Server started at port ${port}`);
    }
  });
});
```

**server.dev**

```
console.log("Development mode.");
const { createServer } = require("https");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const fs = require("fs");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev: devMode, dir: ".", quiet: false });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./certs/cert.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./certs/cert.pem"),
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(httpsOptions, (req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Port: ${port}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [article](https://im5tu.io/article/2017/06/ensuring-secure-cookies-with-url-rewrite/) to set cookie in rewritten rule.

```
<rewrite>
<outboundRules> 
    <rule name="Ensure secure Cookies" preCondition="Missing secure cookie">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; secure" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="Missing secure cookie">
            <!-- Don't remove the first line here, it does do stuff! -->
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; secure" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
    </preconditions>
</outboundRules>
```

I'm not an expert on node. But IIS url rewrite can make rewritten url is also https.  In this case, I think it is very unlikely that the node app will receive an http request.

Comment: Sorry for delayed feedback. I've tried this before and sadly I couldn't get any result. I will try to build my server with express instead of node http module. After that I'll either edit this comment or create answer depending on the result.