# Passport req.isAuthenticated() always returning false,and req.user() is undefined

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, session-cookies, passport-facebook

I am using **passport-facebook** and **express-session** for storing sessions of users on the server side.
The session is getting stored in mongo,and cookie is also getting set in browser,but **req.isAuthenticated()** is returning false,and **req.user()** is undefined.

**passport.deserializeUser** is also working fine.

Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: Difficult to say without any code! Have you setup the passport middleware?

Comment: Your passport success redirect "config.facebookAuth.redirect", this does not exist in your config file

Answer (score 1):

For me,it was a CORS issue.Though the cookie was properly set in browser by passport,but it was not getting sent back by the subsequent axios requests.So both req.isAuthenticated() and req.user() were not working.

To make it work,I had to set the following in client side:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and following in server side(NodeJS + express):

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true);
  next();
});
```