# Passport + NodeJs + Express getting "req.user" undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am facing a session problem, Getting **req.user** undefined  after successful passport. authenticate method.

Basically after signUp or login, when I am redirecting, unable to find "user" in request variable.

I have used a hackathon starter which was using mongo, I tried to change things to use Postgres.

**Edit -- After following suggestions on Comment**

Now signup flow is working fine, but login flow having some problem. Something weird happening, when I am adding a lot of breaking points, It seems to do login intermittently. Update code with comment suggestions

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
const lusca = require('lusca');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const flash = require('express-flash');
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const expressStatusMonitor = require('express-status-monitor');
const sass = require('node-sass-middleware');
const multer = require('multer');

dotenv.load({ path: '.env.example' });

const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
const models = require('./models');

const upload = multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads') });
/**
 * Load environment variables from .env file, where API keys and passwords are configured.
 */

/**
 * Controllers (route handlers).
 */
const homeController = require('./controllers/home');
const userController = require('./controllers/user');
const contactController = require('./controllers/contact');
const dashController = require('./controllers/dash');
const currencyController = require('./controllers/currency');
const accountController = require('./controllers/account');
const testController = require('./controllers/test');
const txController = require('./controllers/transaction');

/**
 * API keys and Passport configuration.
 */
const passportConfig = require('./config/passport');

/**
 * Create Express server.
 */
const app = express();


/**
 * Express configuration.
 */
app.set('host', '127.0.0.1');
app.set('port', 8080);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(expressStatusMonitor());
app.use(compression());
app.use(sass({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: { maxAge: 1209600000 }, // two weeks in milliseconds
  store: new SequelizeStore({
    db: models.sequelize
  })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // if (req.path === '/api/upload') {
  //   next();
  // } else {
  //   lusca.csrf()(req, res, next);
  // }
  next();
});
app.use(lusca.xframe('SAMEORIGIN'));
app.use(lusca.xssProtection(true));
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // After successful login, redirect back to the intended page
  if (!req.user
    && req.path !== '/login'
    && req.path !== '/signup'
    && !req.path.match(/^\/auth/)
    && !req.path.match(/\./)) {
    req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
  } else if (req.user
    && (req.path === '/account' || req.path.match(/^\/api/))) {
    req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
  }
  next();
});
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/js/lib', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/chart.js/dist'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/js/lib', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/js/lib', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/js/lib', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/webfonts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));

/**
 * Primary app routes.
 */
app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
app.post('/login', userController.postLogin);
app.get('/logout', userController.logout);
app.get('/forgot', userController.getForgot);
app.post('/forgot', userController.postForgot);
app.get('/reset/:token', userController.getReset);
app.post('/reset/:token', userController.postReset);
app.get('/signup', userController.getSignup);
app.post('/signup', userController.postSignup);
// app.get('/account', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.getAccount);
// app.post('/account/profile', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.postUpdateProfile);
app.post('/account/password', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.postUpdatePassword);
// app.post('/account/delete', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.postDeleteAccount);
// app.get('/account/unlink/:provider', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.getOauthUnlink);
app.get('/dashboard', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, dashController.index);
app.get('/test', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, testController.test);
// app.get('/contact', contactController.contact);
// app.post('/addContact', contactController.addContact);
// app.post('/editContact', contactController.editContact);
// app.get('/listContacts', contactController.listContacts);
// app.get('/listCurrency', currencyController.listCurrency);
// app.post('/addAccount', accountController.addAccount);
// app.post('/editAccount', accountController.editAccount);
// app.get('/listAccounts', accountController.listAccounts);
// app.get('/getTransactions', txController.getTransactions);


/**
 * Error Handler.
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // only use in development
  app.use(errorHandler());
} else {
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  });
}

/**
 * Start Express server.
 */

models.sequelize.sync({}).then(() => {
  app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('%s App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode', chalk.green('✓'), app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
    console.log('Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**user.js**

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const passport = require('passport');
const models = require('../models');

const { User } = models;

const randomBytesAsync = promisify(crypto.randomBytes);

/**
 * GET /login
 * Login page.
 */
exports.getLogin = (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  res.render('account/login', {
    title: 'Login'
  });
};

/**
 * POST /login
 * Sign in using email and password.
 */
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.assert('password', 'Password cannot be blank').notEmpty();
  req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ gmail_remove_dots: false });

  const errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }

  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('errors', info);
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
res.locals.user = user; //Updated code after comment suggestions
      req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! You are logged in.' });
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};

/**
 * GET /logout
 * Log out.
 */
exports.logout = (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) console.log('Error : Failed to destroy the session during logout.', err);
    req.user = null;
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};

/**
 * GET /signup
 * Signup page.
 */
exports.getSignup = (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  res.render('account/signup', {
    title: 'Create Account'
  });
};

/**
 * POST /signup
 * Create a new local account.
 */
exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.assert('password', 'Password must be at least 4 characters long').len(4);
  req.assert('confirmPassword', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
  req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ gmail_remove_dots: false });

  const errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
  User.findAll({ limit: 1, where: { email: req.body.email }, plain: true })
    .then((existingUser) => {
      if (existingUser) {
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.' });
        return res.redirect('/signup');
      }
      User.create({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      }).then((user) => {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
res.locals.user = user; //updated code after comment suggestions 
          return res.redirect('/');
        });
      }).catch(error => next(error));
    });
};
```

**passport.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const request = require('request');
const { Strategy: LocalStrategy } = require('passport-local');
const _ = require('lodash');

const models = require('../models');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  models.User.findAll({ where: { id }, limit: 1, plain: true })
    .then(user => done(null, user))
    .catch(err => done(err));
});

/**
 * Sign in using Email and Password.
 */
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
  models.User.findAll({ where: { email }, limit: 1, plain: true }).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { msg: `Email ${email} not found.` });
    }
    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
      return done(null, false, { msg: 'Invalid email or password.' });
    });
  }).catch(error => done(error));
}));

/**
 * OAuth Strategy Overview
 *
 * - User is already logged in.
 *   - Check if there is an existing account with a provider id.
 *     - If there is, return an error message. (Account merging not supported)
 *     - Else link new OAuth account with currently logged-in user.
 * - User is not logged in.
 *   - Check if it's a returning user.
 *     - If returning user, sign in and we are done.
 *     - Else check if there is an existing account with user's email.
 *       - If there is, return an error message.
 *       - Else create a new account.
 */

/**
 * Login Required middleware.
 */
exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/login');
};


/**
 * Authorization Required middleware.
 */
exports.isAuthorized = (req, res, next) => {
  const provider = req.path.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  const token = req.user.tokens.find(token => token.kind === provider);
  if (token) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect(`/auth/${provider}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node + Express + Passport: req.user Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434893/node-express-passport-req-user-undefined)

Comment: Man it worked.. thank you.. also can you explain why this was needed. and also I aded " res.locals.user = user;" before redirecting. it is correct way to add it.

Comment: Oh glad it worked for you. That's how I pass my user object in the requests. More explanations here: [app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals)

Comment: This is weird, Not working properly, It's sometimes login and sometimes not. I think It's asyc calls problem somewhere..Not able to figure out where

Answer (score 2):

In your `app.js`, you need to call `const passportConfig = require('./config/passport');` after you initialize `passport`, like so:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// place it here
const passportConfig = require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

Further, you need to **adjust your password config file** (`./config/passport`), so that on module loading **it can get the `passport` instance that you instantiated in `app.js`**, and **subsequently uses it instead of loading a new `passport` instance via `require('passport')`** - this in my opinion messes things up; didn't test it though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the user object sample which refer to this code in your passport.js LocalStrategy

```
user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {....});
```

looks like user.id is not available in serializeuser below which may be the cause it cant set user.id in the session and cant deserialize User further not setting the user object in req

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});
```