# Passport + Express + Typescript req.user.email undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

Well, I have this a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434893/node-express-passport-req-user-undefined) (I know that is similar to another one). But `req.user` was undefined until I installed [@types/passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/passport).

Now I get this problem in VS Code despites I have my session instantiation on my server.

#### The problem

[image: The problem]

#### The instantiation

```js
// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(logger(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'dev' : 'combined'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? process.env.SESSION_SECRET : 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

No errors above. Therefore... the app in fact works... but I get this "error color" on my VSC file that would be great to avoid. Any suggestions?

Just in case, I will include the whole router file:

```js
// POST - Crear usuario
router.post('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const resultado: IResultado = {
        data: null,
        ok: false
    };
    const messages: Array<object> = [];
    const datos: IUsuario = req.body;

    // Validación de campos
    if (!validator.isEmail(datos.email)) {
        messages.push({ email: 'El correo electrónico es inválido'});
    }

    if (validator.isLength(datos.password, { max: 5})) {
        messages.push({ password: 'La contraseña debe tener como mínimo seis caracteres' });
    }

    if (!validator.isMobilePhone(datos.telefono, ['es-UY'])) {
        messages.push({ telefono: 'El número de teléfono es inválido' });
    }

    if (!empty(messages)) {
        resultado.message = 'No se pudo crear el usuario';
        resultado.messages = messages;
        return res.json(resultado);
    }

    datos.password = await bcrypt.hash(datos.password, 10);
    datos.fechaCreacion = Date.now();
    datos.fechaActualizacion = Date.now();

    if (req.user && req.user) {
        datos.propietario = req.user.email;
    }

    const ref: any = db.collection('usuarios').doc(datos.email);

    const doc = await ref.get();

    if (doc.exists) {
        // Usuario ya existe
        resultado.message = 'El correo electrónico ya está en uso';
        return res.json(resultado);
    }
    try {
        await ref.set(datos);
        delete datos.password;
        resultado.message = 'Usuario creado correctamente';
        resultado.data = datos;
        resultado.ok = true;
        return res.json(resultado);
    } catch(error) {
        resultado.message = 'No se pudo crear el usuario';
        resultado.error = error;
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json(resultado);
    }
});
```

#### The `User` interface (`@types/passport` module)

```js
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
        interface AuthInfo {}
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
        interface User {}

        interface Request {
            authInfo?: AuthInfo;
            user?: User;
...
```

Comment: Are you sure `user` has own property email? It looks like not but probably you can initialize it manualny. By default it contains only `username` and `id` properties

Comment: it doesn't. But is defined inside `@types/passport` module. I will extend it as you mentioned.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to extend the `Express.User` type:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User {
      email: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should put this code? I have similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340135/property-admin-does-not-exist-on-type-user-ts2339?noredirect=1#comment127798285_72340135

Comment: A little tip: if your ts file is not a module, you need to write like this:

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface User {
      email: string;
    }
}

```

Answer (score 3):

I think all you need to do is extend basic `User` type interface. That already was asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/91c229dbdb653dbf0da91992f525905893cbeb91#r34805708).

```js
interface User extends SomeOtherUserTypeYouHaveDefined {
      email?: string;
      alsoAnyOtherPropertyYourCodeSetsOnUser: number;
    }
```

Comment: yes, but I did search for it. I didn't find it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not mocking you, because it is not easy to find. Just wanted to provide first-hand contrubitor solution